# External USB 3 Blu Ray

Tags: blu-ray

I am running Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon 64-bit on a LabTop 1.5 GHz 8 GB Ram.

I need to buy an external Blu Ray drive for loading my Blu Ray Movie-discs onto my harddrive and convert them via MakeMkv or HandBrake.

Can anyone recommend an external USB 3 Blu drive that works with Linux Mint?

And which tips and tricks is needed to know, to get this to work.

Regards from Peter.